# Using Python list to query Google App Engine datastore

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, gql

I have created a form in my Google App Engine application for users to select items from a list, the specific details of which (ex. name, other properties) will then be pulled from a datastore table called Item and displayed in a table once the user submits the form.

I have a Python list that contains the keys for the entries selected, pulled from the form.  I want to use this list to look-up entries in the datastore and return them in a way that I can pass to a Django template.

I have tried to follow advice on this forum to use GQL Queries, but all I get thus far are empty results, whether using `fetch()`, hardcoding the key values, trying to use some variation of `WHERE Key IN :list` or `WHERE Key = :variable`.

If you need code, let me know which parts would be helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`db.get(list_of_keys)`

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/functions.html